# How to connect MS Access to hosted SQL database?

Tags: sql, odbc, odbc-sql-server-driver

How to create ODBC or DSN file for connection so that Access Linked Tables are pointing to hosted SQL Tables?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can connect to the SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio, you can use MS Access to connect as well

**Start / Run** "ODBCAD32.exe"

Create a DSN for that SQL Server with the appropriate information.

In MS Access, you can now create linked tables that use your new DSN.

Comment: Connection failed:
SQLState: '01000'
SQL Server Error: 10061
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][TCP/IP Sockets]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).